# Using an optimizer from the backend in keras

Tags: keras

I can see that keras has reimplemented the optimizers. I would like to use an optimizer that is not available in keras, but is available in the backend, e.g. from tensorflow:

```
tf.train.FtrlOptimizer
```

Could you please guide me with some bullet points what would I need to do, to hack the framework, to be able to use an optimizer from the backend?

Thank you,
Jozef

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK figured it out, the hack was to add in a wrapper optimizer

Comment: Would you mind sharing your findings in more detail? How did you add the wrapper optimizer more specifically?